# Connect file scan protection to my site

Tags: php, html, security, web

I am looking into implementing a virus scanner into a web application I am creating that allows the user to upload files. All the background functionality is completed, however I am wary that a malicious user may upload a virus and other users download that file.

I have been researching for a few months now on how to implement a scanner into my web application.

I have located various online virus scanners such as MetaScan-Online and VirusTotal.

I have read into the documentation that they have provided, however I am still confused and am unsure if I can implement these applications into my applications using the API.

Can I?

And if so, is there another virus scanner that enables a whole folder of files to be scanned simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the anti-virus force is strong in you, then you can probably implement a service class and upload the incoming files to one of the public scan services.
Keep in mind that they are limiting the accepted file size and number of files and that they don't store the scan reports forever.

**MetaScan**

The public API for Metascan is described here: https://www.metascan-online.com/public-api#!/

There is also a PHP checker available. But it uses v1 of their API and looks outdated. Maybe contact them to get an update version using API v2.
https://www.metascan-online.com/apps#!/php-metascan-online-checker

**VirusTotal**

The public API is described here: https://www.virustotal.com/de/documentation/public-api/

There are multiple libraries for PHP available, just to mention one of them
https://github.com/jayzeng/virustotal_apiwrapper

**Local clamAV scan after upload**

Another solution is to simply trigger a clamav scan by using `clamscan` after a file was uploaded to your server. That means upload to sandboxed av-scan folder, scan, drop (if bad), or keep (if ok) and finally move to upload folder. This is slow, because signatures have to be loaded each time the clamscan command is invoked from PHP.

With sandbox folder i mean an restricted system environment for controlling the resources better, e.g. an "upload directory" with restricted or removed read/write/exec permissions (user/group/other), isolated from the application, not accessible from the web and with restricted PHP capabilities (think of disable_functions directive).

When your server runs a clamav daemon (`clamd`) its possible to invoke `clamdscan` on the folder. This solution is fast, because the signatures a kept in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response and a detailed answer. I was just a little confused about one aspect. By sandbox folder, do you mean sub domain? Or is there an actual way to create a sandbox folder on filezilla?

Comment: With sandbox folder i mean an restricted system environment for controlling the resources better, e.g. an "upload directory" with restricted or removed read/write/exec permissions (user/group/other), isolated from the application, not accessible from the web and with restricted PHP capabilities (think of disable_functions directive). -- Filezilla FTP allows to create a new folder and change its permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. So do I download clam scan from clamAvs site? Then put the clam scan into the sandbox directory. Then create folders within the sandbox (drop and keep). And through the use of PHP send files to the sandbox when the user uploads the file, trigger the scan via PHP, then redirect the file into the neccessary folder (drop and/or keep). The send the file out of the sandbox folder into a folder that has no restrictions (i.e. not a sandbox).

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. To install ClamAV on a Debian box you could run `sudo apt-get update` + `sudo apt-get install clamav` on the command line. You find install instructions for other OS'es on their website: http://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav

Comment: On the command line of Debian box? And I have done some research and I am a little unsure of what Debian box is, please could you provide me with a link or just a give me a short description please?

Comment: A server running the Debian linux distribution. https://www.debian.org/index.de.html (I assumed that your server uses that.. but i guess i'm wrong. So, please follow the ClamAV installation instructions for your OS.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to handle the sending of folder yourself, they'll not bez able (as an external service) to get the list of file for a defined folder.

[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/fr/documentation/public-api/) is providing a public API to scan your file, it's a good start. You could implement multi threading and store the result for each file. This way you'll avoid sending multiple time the same file.